# How do I start the iteration at a different number?

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a program in python. I have to use the os function to be able to execute a command inside the terminal within my code.

For example:

```
os.system('some_command_%d')
```

I have this inside a while loop to continuously run this command to save files on to my computer such as `file1.txt` `file2.txt`. As you can see the `%d` is used to iterate the name of the files to save it as something new each time. I was wondering if there was anyway do this same process with similar output file names and start them at a different number, i.e. set them to start at `file20.txt` or `file38.txt` just to give an example. This number will be an unknown set value that will be determined within the code and saved as an integer.